# In a ScrollView, can I run a def if I reach the end of the list in a ScrollView or MDList?

Tags: list, kivy, kivymd

***How can I receive the event if I reach the bottom or end of the list***

> In a ScrollView, can I run a def if I reach the end of the list in a ScrollView or MDList?

App.py

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import kivymd_extensions.akivymd
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

img = ["https://ar.anime-slayer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Ashampoo_Snap_2022.04.11_20h41m49s_005_-215x300.webp", "03.jpg", "13.jpg", "15.jpg", "24.jpg", "28.jpg", "29.jpg", "33.jpg", "34.jpg"]
KV = """

<MyTile@SmartTile>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"

ScrollView:
    id: scroll
    MDGridLayout: 
        id: grid 
        cols: 3 
        adaptive_height: True 
        padding: dp(4), dp(4) 
        spacing: dp(4)
        MyTile: 
            source:"https://ar.anime-slayer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Ashampoo_Snap_2022.04.11_20h41m49s_005_-215x300.webp"

        MyTile: 
            source:"15.jpg"
            
        MyTile: 
            source:"24.jpg"
            
        MyTile: 
            source:"13.jpg"                                 
"""


        
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        #self.ids.grid.add_widget(SmartTile(source = img[0])) 
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    
Test().run()
```

Comment: Did you try with `scroll_y` value ?

Comment: No, what do I pass to her as a possible example?

Comment: Try adding that functionality that you want to implement with scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a callback method to the prop. `scroll_y` or override default method `on_scroll_y` with the necessary logic which, if not implemented properly, can be unstable.

However adding a `Button` at the end of your widget tree inside `ScrollView` and triggering an event once you reach the end can be simple and suitable for your needs.

Here is the implementation of that design.

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.factory import Factory
import kivymd_extensions.akivymd
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


img = ["https://ar.anime-slayer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Ashampoo_Snap_2022.04.11_20h41m49s_005_-215x300.webp", "03.jpg", "13.jpg", "15.jpg", "24.jpg", "28.jpg", "29.jpg", "33.jpg", "34.jpg"]

KV = """

<MyTile@SmartTile>
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "240dp"

ScrollView:
    id: scroll

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        adaptive_height: True

        MDGridLayout: 
            id: grid 
            cols: 3 
            adaptive_height: True
            padding: dp(4), dp(4) 
            spacing: dp(4)
            MyTile: 
                source:"https://ar.anime-slayer.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/Ashampoo_Snap_2022.04.11_20h41m49s_005_-215x300.webp"

            MyTile: 
                source:"15.jpg"
            
            MyTile: 
                source:"24.jpg"
            
            MyTile: 
                source:"13.jpg"
        
        Button:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: dp(25)
            text: "Load more photos"
            on_release: app.add_more_images()



"""


        
class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)
    
    def add_more_images(self, *args):
        grid = self.root.ids.grid
        # Add images from the list.
        for img_src in img:
            tile = Factory.MyTile(source = img_src)
            grid.add_widget(tile)
    
Test().run()
```